# Why does codecvt_utf8 give hex value as ffffff appended in beginning?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, codecvt

for this code -

```
int main()
{
    std::wstring wstr = L"é";
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

    for (auto c : myconv.to_bytes(wstr))
    {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(c);
    }
    string ssss = ss.str();
    cout << "ssss = " << ssss << endl;
```

Why does this print  ffffffc3ffffffa9
instead of c3a9?

Why does it append ffffff in beginning?
If you want to run it in ideone - https://ideone.com/qZtGom

Comment: Becuase the `sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(unsigned)` and `wchar_t is probably signed` as a result, there is a conversion that preserves the value of the last bit.

Comment: @MartinYork   even if i cast to int, it still has ffffff appended in beginning

Comment: The problem is the sign extension. `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)` Make sure the object you are initially working with is unsigned. Then you can extend it if you require.

Comment: Try this: `static_cast<unsigned char>(c & 0xFF)`

Comment: @MartinYork why does sign extension occur here?

Comment: It seems like `std::wstring_convert::to_bytes()` is returning a [byte string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes).  Each member of that byte string is a signed type (in your implementation). Note: `char` is either `signed` or `unsigned` depending on implementation (you have to manually check (or read the docs)). So hear I am just making sure it is an `unsigned char` before allowing the object to be put in a larger type (thus avoiding sign extension.

Comment: @MartinYork Also, it promotes the char to an int right, because char is only 8 bits so it can only store the c3 thus the other ffffff is stored in the other 3 bytes of the int right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c` is of type `char`, which is signed on most systems.
Converting a `char` to an unsigned causes value to be sign-extended.

Examples:

- char(0x23) aka 35   --> unsigned(0x00000023)
- char(0x80) aka -128 --> unsigned(0xFFFFFF80)
- char(0xC3) aka -61  --> unsigned(0xFFFFFFc3)

[edit: My first suggestion didn't work; removed]

You can cast it twice:
`ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));`

The first cast gives you an unsigned type with the same bit pattern, and since `unsigned char` is the same size as `char`, there is no sign extension.

But if you just output `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)`, the stream will treat it as a character, and print .. something .. depending on your locale, etc.

The second cast gives you an int, which the stream will output correctly.

Comment: Still returns same results if i cast to an int - for this code -

https://ideone.com/qZtGom

Comment: This will do what you want, but it's ugly: `ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));`
Cast the value to an unsigned type which is the same size as `char`, and then to an `int`, and output it as hex two characters wide.

Comment: why does sign extension occur here?